# How do I get unique element from a vector, keeping its name?

Tags: r, unique, subset

I know there is the function `unique()` that extracts the unique values from a vector. But I lose its name.

Ex.

```
vector = c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "A" = 1, "C" = 3, "B" = 2, "D" = 3, "D" = 3)
```

If I print I should see:

```
A B A C B D D
1 2 1 3 2 3 3
```

**Expected output**:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 3
```

---

Attempts:

If I use: `unique(vector)` I only get `1 2 3`

If I use: `vector[!duplicated(vector)]` I get:

```
A B C 
1 2 3
```

This is close, but the `"D" = 3` is missing.

Comment: `x[!duplicated(paste(x, names(x)))]`?

Answer (score 8):

```
vector = c(A=1,B=2,A=1,C=3,B=2,D=3,D=3)
```

When you do,

```
vector[!duplicated(vector)]
```

it looks for duplicates in values of `vector` and not names hence the output which you get is

```
A B C 
1 2 3
```

If you want to find unique names then you should run `duplicated` function on the `names` of the `vector`

```
vector[!duplicated(names(vector))]

A B C D 
1 2 3 3
```

---

Also similar ouptut could be achieved using `unique`

```
vector[unique(names(vector))]

A B C D 
1 2 3 3
```

Comment: I think they want unique on the values, try: `vector = c(A=1,B=2,A=1,C=3,B=2,D=3,D=4)`

Comment: Great! I just saw I made a mistake on the vector, but yes this is what I needed!

Comment: I'd simply do this : `v[!duplicated(names(v)) | !duplicated(v)]`

Comment: @SaulGarcia this is not what you want, try with D=3 and D=4 instead of D=3, D=3.

Comment: @zx8754 If I have understood OP correctly, they just need unique names and not unique names and unique values.

Comment: If that is the case, why not just use `unique(names(v))`  ?

Comment: @zx8754 because OP needs the values of those names as well.

Comment: So if it is "D=3,D=4", then we just pick the first one?

Comment: Atleast `duplicated` does that. If OP has different requirement they can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match`

```
vector[match(unique(names(vector)), names(vector))]
# A B C D 
# 1 2 3 3
```

or with `tapply`

```
tapply(vector, names(vector), FUN = head, 1)
#  A B C D 
# 1 2 3 3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(Key = names(vector), Value = c(vector))[, Value[1L], Key]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another alternative that also may cover discripancy between values and names

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(value = v, name = names(v)) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>% # alternatively: group_by(name) if name value pair is always unique
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Excellent solution, just that `group_by` can be slow when the df is large.